# Is it possible to swizzle deinit using swift. if yes then how to achieve this

Tags: ios, swift, swizzling, deinit

I want to log some statements in deinit in each subclass of UIViewController in my project. I don't want to copy/paste the same lines in each view controller subclass.

Comment: Are you talking about just custom view controllers you create or do you also need this for standard view controllers provided by the iOS SDK?

Comment: My current need is for custom view controllers but my concern is to check the swizzle availability for deint.

Comment: Did you found any solutions?

Comment: Still not found. @Paul

Comment: Aaaahhhhh, we need this!

Answer (score 9):

There is a  way to achieve this.

You can't swizzle `deinit`, but you can swizzle another method like `viewDidLoad` to poison the class with `associatedObject`. When viewController deallocates, the associatedObject gets deallocated as well.

```
final class Deallocator {

    var closure: () -> Void

    init(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    deinit {
        closure()
    }
}

private var associatedObjectAddr = ""

extension UIViewController {

    @objc fileprivate func swizzled_viewDidLoad() {
        let deallocator = Deallocator { print("Deallocated") }
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &associatedObjectAddr, deallocator, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        swizzled_viewDidLoad()
    }

    static let classInit: Void = {
        let originalSelector = #selector(viewDidLoad)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzled_viewDidLoad)
        let forClass: AnyClass = UIViewController.self
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector)
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
    }()
}
```

**Caveat**

The closure will not get called *exactly* when viewController is deallocated, since the `Deallocator` is deallocated **after** viewController is completely deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the solution that indirectly calls swift code, might not be the best. You can get the de-init implementation by using `NSSelectorFromString` and extend the implementation with swizzling and call swift code through bridging. Try this code that might help you:

```
//
//  UIViewController+ExtendDealloc.h
//  extension
//
//  Created by Amir Kamali on 26/2/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Amir Kamali. All rights reserved.
//

@import UIKit;

@interface UIViewController (ExtendDealloc)


@end
```

.m file:

```
//
//  UIViewController+ExtendDealloc.m
//  extension
//
//  Created by Amir Kamali on 26/2/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Amir Kamali. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UIViewController+ExtendDealloc.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "test_objc-Swift.h"


@implementation UIViewController (ExtendDealloc)

#pragma mark - Swizzle Dealloc
+ (void)load {
    // is this the best solution?
    method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod(self.class, NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc")),
                                   class_getInstanceMethod(self.class, @selector(swizzledDealloc)));
}

- (void)swizzledDealloc {
    [CustomBehaviorHandler printMe];
    [self swizzledDealloc];
}

@end
```

Swift code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomBehaviorHandler:NSObject {

    @objc
    static func printMe() {
        print("deinitializing ....")
    }
}
```

**[UPDATED]**

Comment: Question is for Swift, can yo also add a Swift sample usage?

Comment: Couldn't see any direct solution, however I updated the above code that indirectly calls swift codes.

Comment: You can't call +load anymore on any extension (here `UIViewController (ExtendDealloc)`) starting with Xcode 10.2 beta 3.