# How to invalidate timer in extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions

I was trying to add a timer property in an extension. The code is as follow

```swift
 @objc public extension RCTTouchHandler {
  static let kSessionTimer = "sessionTimer"
  
   var sessionTimer: Timer {
    get {
      return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, RCTTouchHandler.kSessionTimer) as? Timer ?? Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: RCTTouchHandler.kSessionExpiredDuration, target: self, selector: #selector(touchSessionExpiration), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    set(timer) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, RCTTouchHandler.kSessionTimer, self, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
  }

  @objc func touchSessionExpiration() {
    print("session expired")
  }

  deinit {
    self.sessionTimer.invalidate()
  }
}
```

Then,`sessionTimer` has strong reference to this object, in the meantime, this object strongly retains `sessionTimer`. To avoid retain-cycle and memory leak, I should invalid the timer when the object is deinitialized.  But, I encountered the following error when trying to invalidate the timer in the deinit func in this extension.

```
Deinitializers may only be declared within a class
```

According to [Swift Doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)

> Extensions can add new convenience initializers to a class, but they cannot add new designated initializers or deinitializers to a class. Designated initializers and deinitializers must always be provided by the original class implementation.

So I am wondering how should I invalidate the timer properly in this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, you cannot implement `deinit { }` in extensions.

---

You could create your own object and implement `deinit { }` there and instead of using `RCTTouchHandler` everywhere, use your own object:

```
@objc extension RCTTouchHandler {
    static let kSessionTimer = "sessionTimer"
}

public class MyTouchHandler: RCTTouchHandler {
    private var timer: Timer? = nil

    var sessionTimer: Timer {
        get {
            guard let timer = timer else {
                let newTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: RCTTouchHandler.kSessionExpiredDuration, target: self, selector: #selector(touchSessionExpiration), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                self.timer = newTimer
                return newTimer
            }
            return timer
        }

        set(timer) {
            self.timer = timer
        }
    }

    @objc func touchSessionExpiration() {
        print("session expired")
    }

    deinit {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep.makes sense. By the way. If using inheritance, no need to use `objc_getAssociatedObject`. would u please update the answer and i will accept it.

Comment: hmm,  use case for extension and inheritance are different. Here, `RCTTouchHandler` 
 is initialized by third-party sdk. I actually would like to hook it and add some logic into it. So, just want to double check if there is no way to do so?

Comment: @Sherlock_RY_Zheng out of the box it is not possible, BUT you could try some tricks with method swizzling, which can be quite dangerous if you do not know what you are doing. [Some ideas about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647504/is-it-possible-to-swizzle-deinit-using-swift-if-yes-then-how-to-achieve-this)